# meta name="viewport" is ignored by browser(?)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

previously in `<HEAD>` it was

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

As you can see issue in screenShots that I have attached below.. there was issue of UI break so then I have updated `<HEAD>` with following code

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=0.9; maximum-scale=0.9; minimum-scale=0.9;" />
```

But Still issue is there

Web page works well with resolution of **1280 X 800** as you can look at this image

[image]

these 3 columns (with black vertical line separated) are the `<td>`
inside that a container with fixed width in px, and I cant change it to % due to some limitations.
only main container have width : 100%,
(**Main container:** with full page width behind all page content-with white BG)

I have attached screen shots of issues with screen resolution

On **1024 X 768**

[image]

As you can see On browser with ratio **1024 X 768** 
"mobile image" is going beyond White box(Main container)

on **1920 X 1080**

[image]

Here browser ratio is **1920 X 1080** and main container (White box) is 100% of width but those three columns (`<TD>`) are not, all three  width remains same as previous images and main container is 100%

**Update:** Code link https://jsfiddle.net/p6x6jsgt/3/

Comment: Where is your CSS?

Comment: The link is unreachable. Anyway, is the container a table, by any chance? Then the `width` property will be treated as `min-width`; if there's more content, a table will make itself wider to fit.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The issue is because of ur fixed width. What is the problem if u change the width to percentage?

Comment: there is text content which should look same within 3 columns, 

1st column contains 2-3 copies smaller scaled version of same mobile preview (RHS), and middle column contains one  larger version.

So I have set font sizes accordingly ..so that line breaks at all 3 columns should be same

thats why I cant assign % values, If I do so, line break at 3 places will be different, and then cant control text block appearance at all columns

Comment: why are you using tables for layout in 2016

Answer (score 7):

The problem is not your `meta` viewport tag. After having read all the comments here are a couple solutions to your problem:

### A non-optimal solution:

Keep the table layout, change to percentage widths and use text blocks with `white-space:nowrap;` and `<br>` hard-coded line breaks with different font sizes depending on device screen size.

**- About the layout:**

Your `.preview-panel` has a fixed width in `rem`. To solve this, make the following changes:

```
.preview-panel {
    background-size:100% auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

Now you will notice layout issues with the other `td`. That's because you have to set them to percentage widths, for example:

```
.template-editor {
    width:100%;
}
.template-editor td {
    width:33%;
}
```

**- About the text blocks:**

You said setting widths to percentages would mess up your text blocks. Well, unfortunately there's no magical solution for this and all you can do about it (with your current layout) is to add this to whatever text block you put in there:

```
.foo {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

You would also have to fix your line breaks with `<br>` like so:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br>
consectetur adipiscing elit.<br>
Fusce pulvinar aliquet luctus.
```

You could make the line breaks responsive if you wanted to, with something like (HTML):

```
<span class="line-break"></span>
```

(CSS):

```
.line-break {
    display:block;
}
```

Then you'd have the opportunity to set different font sizes on your media queries, and you could also hide the purposeful line-breaks with `display:none;`. This is, in my opinion, a better solution than plain old `<br>`.

With this, your layout should look better in all devices. That being said, this is still a poor solution and an entirely different approach is necessary, in my opinion.

### A better solution:

Use `flex` or maybe just floated items, but not a `table` when your layout essentially is not a table. You have three panels, why would you forcefully use a table layout for that? Here's an example with flex:

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  align-items:stretch;
  justify-content:center;
}
.container__panel {
  flex-grow:1;
  height:600px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__panel"></div>
  <div class="container__panel"></div>
  <div class="container__panel"></div>
</div>
```

Disclaimer: the weird `container__panel` is BEM notation: http://getbem.com/introduction/

Comment: I appreciate this answer but I don't think <BR> will work for me, coz text block are from back-end(not static text) so cant controls its HTML, those are styled with text editor so its not just a text block it includes several html to style that text block (<b>, <ul>, <ol> etc)

Comment: Then you can add `position:absolute;` so the text won't wrap and it will stay as it is.

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
td{
    width: 33%;
}
```

For dividing the columns equally ,

Remove  width css from the below class so that it can adjust width according to parent class (i have commented the code which i have removed from css)

```
  #cardListHolder {
        padding-top: 0.4375rem;
        /*width: 21.5625rem;*/
    }

 .edit-card .inner {
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0 2.1875rem;
    /*  width: 18.75rem;*/
    }
.preview-panel {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://cdnsq.ur-nl.com/assets/mobile-898fc89b167945138c3d9f551a5ce551.png") no-repeat scroll center 0;
        height: 26.25rem;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 3.4375rem 0.8125rem 0;
     /* width: 13.3125rem;*/
    }
```

Just try replacing this whole css with your css. I hope this will fix your issue.

```
    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    ul {
        list-style: outside none none;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .sectional-content {
        background: #f6f6f6;
        color: #222;
        cursor: auto;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 1.5;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
    }

    .wrapper {
        min-height: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }

    .centered-container {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 96.6667%;
        padding-left: 0.3125rem;
        padding-right: 0.3125rem;
        position: relative;
    }

    .tabs-content {
        background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
        border: 1px solid red;
        margin-top: -1px;
        padding: 1.5625rem;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .divider1 {
        height: 18px;
    }

    .template-editor {
        background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
        border: 0 none;
        margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
        table-layout: auto;
    }

    .template-editor tr {
        background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
    }

    td{
        width: 33%;
    }

    .add-remove-template,
    .edit-card {
        padding-top: 5px !important;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .add-remove-template {
        border-left: 0 none;
        padding-left: 0 !important;
        padding-right: 0 !important;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    table tr th,
    table tr td {
        color: #222;
        font-size: 0.875rem;
        padding: 0.5625rem 0.625rem;
        text-align: left;
    }

    #cardListHolder {
        padding-top: 0.4375rem;
    }

    .preview-template,
    .edit-card {
        border-left: 2px solid #808285;
        padding: 0 1.875rem !important;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .edit-card .inner {
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0 2.1875rem;
    }

    .preview-panel {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://cdnsq.ur-nl.com/assets/mobile-898fc89b167945138c3d9f551a5ce551.png") no-repeat scroll center 0;
        height: 26.25rem;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 3.4375rem 0.8125rem 0;
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't just paste a code answer and say 'Replace with this'. It would be really helpful to explain what's different, and help the poster understand what has been changed, and why.

Comment: i have added explanation to the answer hope it helps you

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this it fits it self in every resolution.

```css
.section {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 16px;
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}
.scroll-container {
  height: 360px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.edit-card {
  height: 360px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.preview-panel img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="section scroll-container" style="height: 360px">
    <ul id="cardListHolder">
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="section edit-card">
    <p>
    edit something
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="section preview-panel">
    <img src="http://cdnsq.ur-nl.com/assets/mobile-898fc89b167945138c3d9f551a5ce551.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can change CSS but - Cant change my HTML layout..sorry

Answer (score 1):

May be over-looking here...
Have you tried using media queries to resolve this?
See if this link is any good.
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en

Of course it would mean alot more coding to get it to work fluently and changes will need to be done.

And have you also used the `text-align: center;` attribute in your css for the text paragraphs in your columns,rather than "setting it perfectly" to align correctly on all three columns followed of course by removing/setting the white space.

From what i can see, i think this may solve your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the defined width you have given in

```
#cardListHolder {
padding-top: 0.4375rem;
width: 21.5625rem;
```

}

and in

```
.edit-card .inner {
margin: auto;
padding: 0 2.1875rem;
width: 18.75rem;
```

}

and use

```
th,td{
width: 33%;
```

}

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
 *, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
}
.sectional-content{
      background: #f6f6f6;
    color: #222;
    cursor: auto;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;

}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.centered-container{
   margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
width: 96.6667%;
padding-left: 0.3125rem;
    padding-right: 0.3125rem;
    position: relative;
}
.tabs-content {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding: 1.5625rem;
     margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.divider1{
  height: 18px;
}
 .template-editor {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 0 none;
    margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
    table-layout: auto;
}
.template-editor tr {
    background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
    position:relative;
}
.add-remove-template, .edit-card {
    padding-top: 5px !important;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.add-remove-template {
    border-left: 0 none;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    vertical-align: top;
}
table tr th, table tr td {
    color: #222;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    padding: 0.5625rem 0.625rem;
    text-align: left;
}
#cardListHolder {
    padding-top: 0.4375rem;
    
}
.preview-template, .edit-card {
    border-left: 2px solid #808285;
    padding: 0 1.875rem !important;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.edit-card .inner {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 2.1875rem;
    
}
.preview-panel {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://cdnsq.ur-nl.com/assets/mobile-898fc89b167945138c3d9f551a5ce551.png") no-repeat scroll center 0;

    height: 26.25rem;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 3.4375rem 0.8125rem 0;
    width: 13.3125rem;
}

th,td{
 width: 33%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sectional-content"> 
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="centered-container">
          <div class="tabs-content">
            <div class="divider1"></div>

            <table class="template-editor" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="add-remove-template">
                    <div class="scroll-container" style="height: 360px">
                      <ul id="cardListHolder">
                        <li></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="edit-card">
                    <div class="inner">
                      
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="preview-template">
                    <div class="preview-panel">
                     
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: still its leave same issue! More white space at right side on bigger screens